# c# keydown code not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a TextBox used to make research by keyword. I have checkboxes to filter the results and also a graph to display occurences of keyword in the table. The search is done once you click on the button made for it, it also works if I click on Enter Key. The problem is that if I decide to check 2 checkboxes and Click on Enter, the research is not made, or if I change the keyword and click again on Enter the result of the graph is not made. I'd like it to work whenever I click on the button or Enter.

I'm using KeyDown like I saw on the internet but it's not changing anythhing, no error either.

My code :

```
        protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Populate();

        }

        protected void tbSearch_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                btnSearch_Click(null, null);
        }
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], we don't want to have to read 100 lines of code.

Comment: The keydown event handler is bound to the textbox so it is triggered only when the textbox has the current input focus. If you want to get it at the form level then you need to set the form KeyPreview property to true and add the handler to the form keydown event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your textbox, just

- add the attribute autopostback="true"
- add the attribute OnTextChanged="btnSearch_Click"

and it will do what you want without JQuery

--> autopostback: postback to server when an event is triggered

--> OnTextChanged: when you get out of textbox (or press enter), the event is triggered and go to your search function

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've found the problem, I didn't mention I was using update Panel.
So here is the code working for me :

```
$('#tbSearch').keydown(function (e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 13)  // the enter key code
    {
        //your code
    }
});
```

To make that code work with updatePanel :

```
//On UpdatePanel Refresh.
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
if (prm != null) {
    prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
        if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {

            $('#tbSearch').keydown(function (e) {
                var key = e.which;
                if (key == 13)  // the enter key code
                {
                  // your code
                }
            });
         }
    });
};
```